# Python packaging with Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, packaging

I am trying to package my python file using Pyinstaller. I follow the instructions from this link 
https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

but I get this error. 
       *RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded.*

I tried to added the following line of code as it was suggested on few pages but so far no success.

```
        **import sys
           sys.setrecursionlimit(1500).**
```

Any help?

Comment: What's your python version and pyinstaller version?

Comment: I run Python 3.7 and latest version of Pyinstaller (pyinstaller) (0.17.1)

Comment: Can you run your code normally?Is there no exception?

Comment: Yes, no issue with running my codes.

Answer (score 0):

Just so you all know the error was caused by Anaconda environment. It is not compatible with Python 3.7 and Pyinstaller. As soon I as uninstall Anaconda and run the Pyinstaller function, everything was fine and I managed to create an exe file.